# Migration of a Windows VM in domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008

Good Morning,

is it possible to remove a server from a domain when the server is not connected to AD?
This is the scenario: I want migrate a test VM in domain to a Cloud that has no access to AD. So after the migration is possible to remove from the domain the server in cloud?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: You can just remove the computer object in AD. It does't require the server to be connected.

Comment: No, i don't want remove the computer when is connected in AD but when is already in cloud.